# php myaql union query with different uid

Tags: mysql

I have some table restore user articles. the table struction like...

```
id | uid | imgae |
1  |  1  | 1.jpg |
2  |  1  |       |
3  |  2  | 2.jpg |
4  |  3  | 3.jpg |
5  |  3  |       |
6  |  3  | 4.jpg |
7  |  4  |       |
...
```

Then I want get 10 result witch `image!=''`

```
(select * from my_table where image!='' order by rand() limit 1)
UNION 
(select * from my_table where image!='' order by rand() limit 1)
UNION 
(select * from my_table where image!='' order by rand() limit 1)
UNION 
(select * from my_table where image!='' order by rand() limit 1)
UNION 
(select * from my_table where image!='' order by rand() limit 1)
UNION 
(select * from my_table where image!='' order by rand() limit 1)
UNION 
(select * from my_table where image!='' order by rand() limit 1)
UNION 
(select * from my_table where image!='' order by rand() limit 1)
UNION 
(select * from my_table where image!='' order by rand() limit 1)
UNION 
(select * from my_table where image!='' order by rand() limit 1)
```

And how to make a further query. 10 result with 10 different `uid` (`a.uid!=b.uid`)? And the code is too long... Any easy way? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the limit and include a group by  :

```
select * from my_table where image!='' order by rand() group by uid limit 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE image != ''
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 10
```

If you just want the `DISTINCT uid` you could do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT uid, id, image FROM my_table
WHERE image != ''
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 10
```

(MySQL people refresh my memory -- when you select `DISTINCT uid` will MySQL pick the corresponding id, image rows or is it more like `GROUP BY` where you don't necessarily get corresponding rows?)